# Syntax to execute code block inside Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

Here's some code that (obviously) doesn't compile:

```
var q = from x in myAnonymousTypeCollection
        select new {
          x.ID,
          CalcField = { 
                        switch(x.SomeField) {
                          case 1:
                            return Math.Sqrt(x.Field1);
                          case 2:
                            return Math.Pow(x.Field2, 2);
                          default:
                            return x.Field3;
                        }
                      }
        };
```

You get the picture; I'm trying to calculate `CalcField` in a completely different way, depending on what the value of `SomeField` is.  I can't use a `Func<>` (or can I?), because the input type is anonymous.  So what's the right syntax to get this to work?

Comment: Is this Linq to Objects?

Comment: Use a lambda or an anonymous function.

Comment: @ofstream - I know I could do it using a lambda, but for reasons of readability in my actual code, I want to use query syntax.

Comment: @cadrell0 - all code is being executed in local memory; it's not going to SQL and doesn't need a translation.

Comment: @ofstream - with an anonymous type parameter?

Answer (score 16):

First off, I usually prefer the method chain syntax over the query syntax for Linq.  With that you can do this easily.

```
var q = myAnonymousTypeCollection
    .Select(x => 
            {
                object calcField; 

                 switch(x.SomeField) 
                 {
                      case 1:
                        calcField = Math.Sqrt(x.Field1);
                      case 2:
                        calcField =  Math.Pow(x.Field2, 2);
                      default:
                        calcField = x.Field3;

                 return new 
                        {
                            x.ID,
                            CalcField = calcField
                        };
            });
```

Without using method chains, you need either a method or an Func.  Let's assume a Func

```
//replace these with actual types if you can.
Func<dynamic, dynamic> calculateField = 
    x => 
    {
        switch(x.SomeField) {
            case 1:
                return Math.Sqrt(x.Field1);
            case 2:
                return Math.Pow(x.Field2, 2);
            default:
                return x.Field3;
    }

var q = from x in myAnonymousTypeCollection
        select new { x.Id, CalcField = calculateField(x) };
```

Note: I didn't write this in an IDE, so please excuse any simple errors.

Here is the MSDN for [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).  However, I have found that once you need to start passing anonymous types around, it is best to make an actual class.

Comment: +1 Ooh, sneaky, using `dynamic`!  I prefer strong types though, and so  far I'm going with the first option (lambda syntax).  Waiting for a valid query syntax (if one exists) before giving you answer credit.  :-)

Comment: I'm diggin' the query syntax. The logic I extracted should have been encapsulated, and naming it makes my Linq query read better. I used a local function instead of lambda (little cleaner?). Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You could wrap your anonymous function as a (self-executing) `Func<>` delegate.  This assumes you know the return type.

```
var q = from x in myAnonymousTypeCollection
    select new {
      ID = x.ID,
      CalcField = new Func<double>( () => { 
                    switch(x.SomeField) {
                      case 1:
                        return Math.Sqrt(x.Field1);
                      case 2:
                        return Math.Pow(x.Field2, 2);
                      default:
                        return x.Field3;
                    }
                  } )()
    };
```

Comment: +1: that's nice! the concept is kind of similar with javascript: execute anonymous function: `(function(){...})();`

Comment: Note that in a situation like this it's probably best from a readability/maintenance standpoint to extract this out to a named function that you simply call in the LINQ query, even though this will work.

Comment: +1 very nice.  What if the return type is also anonymous?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could quite easily move the switch logic out into another function like so:

```
private static T GetReturnValue<T>(myClass x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case 1:
            return Math.Sqrt(x.Field1);
            break;
        case 2:
            return Math.Pow(x.Field2,
                            2);
            break;
        default:
            return x.Field3;
            break;
    }
}
```

And then you just need to pass your object to that function to get back the value you want:

```
var q = from x in myAnonymousTypeCollection
                    select new
                        {
                            ID = x.ID,
                            CalcField = GetReturnValue(x)
                        };
```

Comment: Sure, that would be easy if I had a defined type, like you do (`myClass`).  But I'm using an anonymous type...